# Can I use JOOQ generated code against another DB schema?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jooq

I am using JOOQ to access a Rails database, and as you know, Rails has three db schemas, "test", "development" and "production". Let's call these schemas TEST, DEV and PROD for now.

Now I have generated code against DEV with (almost) this setup in library.xml

```
<jdbc>
  <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
  <url>jdbc:mysql://<ip-address>:3306/data_dev</url>
  <user>secret</user>
  <password>secret</password>
</jdbc>
```

I connect using code like:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + 
    db_host + "/" + 
    db_schema + "?" + 
    "user=" + db_user + 
    "&password=" + db_pass;

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
dsl = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
```

Now I want to run the code against PROD, which is identical in structure, but of course have production data.

However, even if I change the connection URL to schema PROD, I still seem to access the DEV? Is the generated code hardcoded to DEV database?

I'm confused how to proceed.

Comment: What does this java code have to do with rails? A DB is just a DB and your using the wrong URL.

Comment: JOOQ is a Java library for accessing a database, which I'm sure you know? I was just explaining why I am using different schemas with the same code. My experience is that I have to explain details like that to avoid a bunch of "Why do you do that, what are you trying to do" - questions. And pls exlpain the part where you say the URL is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can change the mapped DB in runtime.

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping/

I completely missed this in the documentation. But thanks for all help anyway...